# Eclipse RCP e4 switch workspace programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I would like to switch the workspace in a pure rcp e4 application in the code. I found the old way that uses the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenWorkspaceAction`.

But this approach doesn't work in a pure e4 app because the application model has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible to do this.

When you run a pure e4 application the main `IApplication` is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application`. This code does not support the special return code used to signal that a change of workspace is required.

You can restart the existing workbench be calling `IWorkbench.restart`. `IWorkbench` is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench` which can be injected.

Comment: Thank you for your help that's what I suspected. Is there a workaround for?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this problem:

The big problem with e4 is that the returing code will not be changed and equinox need a IApplication.EXIT_RESTART code.

Workaround:
- First implement the IApplication interface (see code below)

```
 public class FrameworkE4Application implements IApplication {
        private static FrameworkE4Application application;
        private Integer exit_code = IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        private E4Application e4Application;

        public static FrameworkE4Application getInstance() {
            return application;
        }

        public void setRestartCode() {
            exit_code = IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
        }

        @Override
        public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
            application = this;
            e4Application = new E4Application();
            e4Application.start(context);
            return exit_code;
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            e4Application.stop();
        }
    }
```

Then you need to register your custom implementation with equinox. For this extend the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point (see below).

```
  <extension id="FrameworkE4Application"
      point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications"> 
      <application> 
         <run  class="FrameworkE4Application"> 
            <parameter name="optimize" value="true"/> 
         </run> 
       </application> 
   </extension>
```

If you would like to start this as product you need to overwritte the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point (see below).

```
 <product
    name="YourProduct"
    application="FrameworkE4Application">
    <property
        name="appName"
        value="ProductPath">
    </property>
 </product>
```

And here is a implementation of an action that restarts your application.

```
public class RestartApplicationAction {
    @Execute
    public void execute(IWorkbench workbench) {
        FrameworkE4Application.getInstance().setRestartCode();
        workbench.close();
    }
}
```

Now you can set the new Location and restart the application with a new workspace.

Comment: If you just want to Restart rather than switch workspaces the standard E4Application supports that by calling `IWorkbench.restart`